# jQuery How to add click to ul

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add class checked on `li` when users click it using jQuery. I have written the below code which works.

HTML

```html
<ul>
    <li class="row">Documents checked</li>
    <li class="row">Documents Verified </li>
    <li class="row">Forwarded to Logistics </li>
    <li class="row">Received by Logistics</li>
</ul>
```

```css
.checked {
  background: green;
}
```

jQuery

```js
$(function() {
    $('li.row').on('click', function() {
      $(this).addClass('checked');
    });
});
```

This is working but I am told this is bad practice and asked to find better way to do this. I do the following but it is not working.

```js
$(function() {
    $('ul').on('click', function(li) {
      $(li).addClass('checked');
    });
});
```

Comment: It's not bad practice ;)

Comment: who said its bad practice?

Comment: Whomever told that it was "bad practice" needs to explain *why* they **think** it is bad practice.  tl;dr it's not.  Your first attempt is the correct way to add event handlers. Your second won't work.  You can use *delegated event handlers* which would be `$("ul").on("click", "li", function() { $(this)...` but they're only needed for dynamically created elements.

Comment: $(li).addClass('checked'); not worked because li is variable not a actual html li.

Comment: If you're trying to make it where you can only click one at a time, then you *could* replace your `li` and js with 4x radio buttons (with css styling) with no need for any js - so it *could* be that this is what they are referring it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    $('ul').on('click', function(li) {
      $(li).addClass('checked');
    });
});
```

it's wrong because you cant select li by click on you ul
if you want to add class or delete class with click you can use (toggleClass) like this

```
$('li').find(.row).on('click', function() {
      $(this).toggleClass('checked');
    });
```

but if you want to just add class write like this

```
$('li').find(.row).on('click', function() {
          $(this).addClass('checked');
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

use this Code for solution your problem

```js
$(".row").click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass("change")
})
```

```css
.change {
  background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li class="row">Documents checked</li>
    <li class="row">Documents Verified </li>
    <li class="row">Forwarded to Logistics </li>
    <li class="row">Received by Logistics</li>
</ul>
```